# How to create mapping between two API's for a common entity

Tags: algorithm, api, rest, automation, integration

There is a transport service app called APP1 and it wants to read data from APP2 which is a GDS. Both these apps have their own set of unique City ID's. What is the best way to get a accurate mapping between the City ID'S of the two APPS.

Ex. 
In APP1 - `{city_name: 'London', 'city_id': 121 }`
In APP2 - `{city_name: 'London (England)', 'city_id': 5021}`

> Proposed Solution:

Create a mapping between the ID'S using the city names by text processing. This will be a one time process as both APPS have all cities in England.
Problem : Manual intervention is required to validate the mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on experience with this kind of data project, what you should do is write a function that takes one name to what you think the other will be.  For example just add `' (England)'` to the APP1 names.  Then match exact duplicates.  Sort the leftovers, and process them manually.

There are a lot of reasons for the leftovers.  Some will be cases where one considered a city to have a different name than the other.  One considered two cities to be one.  One is abbreviated differently than the other.  Some will take research.

Trying to get all of those edge cases right is a lost cause.  Which is why the hybrid of easy automation then manual processing of what is left works better than trying to automate the whole thing.